# Oscillatory integrals with critical points clustering on a submanifold of positive codimension

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-analysis, oscillatory-integral

In Stein's manuscript "Harmonic Analysis: Real-Variable Methods, Orthogonality and Oscillatory Integrals", oscillatory integrals with discrete critical points are proven. I heard that you have nice bounds even if critical points cluster, as long as they don't converge in every direction; that is, clustering on a sub manifold of positive codimension. But Stein's method doesn't work in the clustering case. Are there any references on clustering critical points?